# Redirect to another page when click on Input

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I am using Ionic3. I want to redirect to another page from a modal form once the user click on an input , I am not sure if thats possible

.html:

```
 <ion-item>
  <ion-label class="labels" stacked>Country</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" formControlName="country" [(ngModel)]="query"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

I already tried placing `(click)="goToCountrySearch()"` in `ion-input` but it doesn't function. Is there a way to accomplish this! thanx

Comment: can you show your code of goToCountrySearch()?

Comment: did not see click, may be you can try focus. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/

Comment: @wannadream `this.viewCtrl.dismiss();` `this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push('CountrySearch');` thats inside `goToCountrySearch()`

Comment: @wannadream you mean to push when the output event focus fires! how to do that ?

Comment: (focus)="goToCountrySearch($event)"

Comment: @wannadream there another problem with modal.. to navigate to another page , the modal is destroyed , I have other fields there as well

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @wannadream I am trying to have an autocomplete input , not a searchbar , I thought to redirect to another page where there is a searchbar... but I guess I'll try another way... where the input filters and shows a drop down list of suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `(input)` instead of `(click)`. The function `goToCountrySearch()` will fire when you type something.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label class="labels" stacked>Country</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" formControlName="country" [(ngModel)]="query" (input)="goToCountrySearch()"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```